# How to ensure that the state of the venv equals the one declared in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

In Python, the `requirements.txt` file declares a set of concrete dependencies of a python application.

Often, during development, dependencies change. When the set of new dependencies overlaps with the set of old dependencies, all is good, as a `venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt` updates them accordingly.

However, when the set of new dependencies is smaller than the set of old dependencies, old dependencies become "dangling" as they are no longer used, but still populate the `pip freeze`.

Is there any command to force pip to ensure that `pip freeze` after a `pip install -r requirements.txt` is the same as declared in the `requirements.txt`?

My current solution is to delete the venv and create a new one, which is mildly time-consuming.

Note that the goal is not to generate a `requirements.txt` file, is to make venv map to a given requirements file.

Comment: A possible alternative is to use `pipenv`, which supports this kind of functionality: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv

Comment: maybe https://pypi.org/project/pip-stripper/ ?  disclaimer:  it’s my puppy.  it does a ‘pip list’ and then cross-checks it vs what your code is importing.  but the versions come from that pip list, not the requirements.txt.  so you could diff its generated req.txt vs your existing req.txt.  the original intent was to strip out outdated or dev-only packages from prod reqs.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like pipreqs could solve your problem, pipreqs will create a requirments.txt file, but only include dependencies that are currently being used in your project (based on the imports in your code)

for more info check their github repo [here](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs)

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear that I am not trying to generate a requirements.txt file.

Comment: Also, the idea that `requirements.txt` can be generated from the source code seems snake oil to me: the goal of `requirements.txt` is to pin specific versions of the dependencies. Given a source code, it is extremely difficult to compute which specific version should be pinned in the requirements. Maybe `pipreqs` is trying to compute the `install_requires`, but even then it is very difficult, since it is not easy to get the version boundaries to specify.